# Will F-2 visa holder lose her/his status the day s/he files divorce/summery dissolution?

Tags: student-visa, us-citizens, marriage, dependent-visa, divorce

I searched on the Google and found out both divorce and summary dissolution filing seem to take 6 months to be approved/legally accepted.

So what would be the status of someone whose visa is a dependent one like a F-2 visa holder?
Should s/he leave the US as soon as the filed the divorce/dissolution?

Also want to know, can s/he get married with somebody else(a US citizen) the day they filed divorce/dissolution? If no, should s/he leave the US and request for remarrying a US citizen or s/he can stay in the state until divorce/dissolution happens then s/he can file a new marriage request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, the two people remain legally married until the divorce is final. So the F-2 spouse can continue to be on F-2 status while the divorce is pending. And neither spouse can re-marry while the divorce is pending.

Comment: In the US, marriage and divorce is civil, not religious. To terminate a marriage, one must go through a dissolution as provided by state law. Usually or often, state law contains a 6-month waiting period. One can get a "tentative" or "provisional" or "interim" decree of dissolution while the divorce proceedings are pending, but the parties are not divorced and cannot remarry until the court issues a final judgment terminating the marriage.